# grails, relations and cascade delete

Tags: database, grails, relation, cascading-deletes

I have the following domain classes:

```
class Patient {
    ...
}

class Receipt{
@NotNull
static belongsTo = [patient:Patient]
...
}
```

If I try to delete a `Patient` instance (after creation of `Receipt` instances), I have a `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. Notice that a patient can have zero-to-many receipts.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, how about add a has many receipt in patient?

Comment: If I have a hasMany in Patient, can it be nullable (to have a zero to many relationship)?

Comment: yes you dont need to manipulate it. It should just be "static hasMany = [receipts: Receipt]"

Comment: but to be nullable I need to add a constraint in domain class for receipts, right?

Comment: You dont have to do anything, the reference is in the Receipt. No extra table column will be added in Patient

Comment: It works! can you give an answer here please, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the parent child relationship, create a has many section in the parent domain class:

```
class Patient {
static hasMany = [receipts: Receipt]
    ...
}

class Receipt{
@NotNull
static belongsTo = [patient:Patient]
...
}
```